# Is it possible to get R intellisense or console output in PowerBI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I've been trying to get started using R in PowerBI. However, the lack of intellisense and the lack of console output is hindering me. As I can't develop the script in RStudio or in Visual Studio with those aids.

EDIT: PowerBI does a nice thing where you can import data into the application and then work with the drag and drop tools to play around with the data, then when you select data fields that you want to add to an R plot, it creates an R stub that pulls those fields into a data.frame which makes things easy. However, that data is "inside" Power BI, I can't do the same thing in R studio because that data context doesn't exist.

What options are there? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Why cant you develop in RStudio or VS, then copy and paste?

Comment: I added an edit to explain that R code would not be runnable anywhere else. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to pull data from PowerBI into RStudio so that you can create R plots in RStudio? Do you want to create a plotting template or function in RStudio that you can run in the application? There appears to be an [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt203567.aspx) that allows the former at least. It seems like you could do the latter just by creating a file that references the data context you create, then `source`ing it after.

Comment: If PowerBI offered consultants evaluation opportunities and a good description of their API, _and_ you offered a working example, it might encourage investigation. Asking "What options are there?" when you are within a "locked box" and don't provide a substrate with a specific question isn't likely to generate much interest. You probably need to pay a consultant to work with you.

Comment: I don't have a specific problem with a particular PowerBI solution. Using R inside PowerBI is not radical in itself, but the R editor that is provided in Power BI is just a text editor. I was asking what other people do to make that more palatable. There would be no point in exporting the innards of PowerBI, the idea is to have an integrated environment.

Comment: It looks like the answer is: there is no option for intellisense and raising it to MS as a requirement is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are looking for is [R tools for VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/rtvs-vs.aspx). It should make intellisense pick up the context and tell you what you can do with each object. Then for the output, can't you print and check the results in the output window in VS?

This also has R interactive window so when you debug you have a window to place code in, and evaluate it in that context. Say you have a method and you want to debug a statement `plot(x, exp(x), type="l", col="green")`, instead of making a fix at a time and then re-running to check the results, you can just make the fix say `plot(x, exp(x), type="l", col="red")` and see how that evaluates. This comes in handy when you wanna try a couple of things and check the results, since you can do it in one go, instead of "making one change and running it" x times.

Let me know if this does the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't get the PowerBI data context exposed outside of the application.

Answer (score 2):

The only data context you have in R inside Power BI are Tables, which you pass in parameters of the call of R.Execute. Behind the scene, these Tables will be just dropped on disk as csv and then R process will pick them in order to do whatever you want. Actually this is the only relation between R and PowerBI desktop, if we speak about Transformations using R.

You can easily save such a context from PowerBI using R script of just one function save.image(“filename.RData”), and then open it using load("filename.RData") in your target R development environment.

Answer (score 1):

While you should always test out your R code elsewhere first, it is often not enough for debugging purposes.

for general purpose debugging, you can nest your whole script in a block like this:

```
out <- capture.ouput({...})
```

Any intermediate value can be captured in this block with a cat:

```
cat(intermediate_value_i_want_to_test,'\n')
```

After your script block is done, simply convert your output to a data.frame and each cat method call will be printed in a new row of out.